# Is AlarmManager the only way to start a task if the application if not running (paused for example)?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, alarmmanager

If I use threads and not alarm manager, what happens with the thread if the application is paused or killed by Android?
Any good picture about sequence diagram with threads, alarm manager, services, etc that makes good understanding of it?
Thanks! Guillermo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadcast receivers registered through manifest will also start the application. Talking of threads and services take a look at the comparisons in this [article](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-thread-constructspart-4.html).